# How to setup a retail price and wholesale price in Odoo

Tags: odoo

for example, product A has 1,000,000 units, each unit is sold at 1$; per 1000 unit is sold $900. so if someone bought 2 thousand and 3 unit, the total sales is $1803.

how should I setup this one in Odoo. I already add a "thousand" unit of measure.

In short how can I setup a price per uom, in this case price for every 1000 is 900

Answer (score 3):

Each pricelist is calculated from defined policies, so you will have as many sales pricelists as active sales policies in the company. 
Creating Price Lists
You can define a pricelist from the menu Sales ‣ Configuration ‣ Pricelists ‣ Pricelists.
For each list you should define:
•   a Name for the list,
•   a Type of list: Sale for customers or Purchase for suppliers,
•   the Currency in which the prices are expressed
[image]

Create  a ‘whole sales pricelist’
[image]

Once the pricelist is defined you have to link at least one version. You can create a new version directly from the pricelist or from the Sales ‣ Configuration ‣ Pricelists ‣ Pricelist Versions menu. The version contains all of the rules that enable you to calculate a price for a product and a given quantity.

Start by setting the Name of this associated version. If the list only has a single version, you can use the same name for the pricelist and the version. In the Price List field, select the pricelist you created (this is not necessary if you create the version directly from the pricelist).

Then set the Start Date and End Date of this version. The fields are both optional: if you do not set any dates the version will be permanently active. Only one version may be active at any one point, so bear this in mind when creating them. Use the Active field in the versions to activate or disable a pricelist version.
[image]

Then Create a pricelist version with in the Name ‘whole sales’, then select the pricelist ‘whole sales pricelist’ we create earlier
[image]

Calculation Rules
A pricelist version is made up of a set of rules that apply to the basic product prices.
To define the rule for the whole sale, click an add item link
[image]